# How to select values on dataframe conditioned to certain string matching a repetead id?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
user_id  event 
1        registration
1        visit
1        purchase
2        registration
2        external
```

I would like to select all values from every user_id which has at least one event of type external in order to store them in another dataframe. So, for this case, I would like to have a dataframe with the next information:

```
user_id  event
2        registration
2        external
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate in-scope user IDs. Then apply a Boolean mask:

```
# calculate unique in-scope IDs
ids = df.loc[df['event'] == 'external', 'user_id'].unique()

# mask dataframe with Boolean series
res = df[df['user_id'].isin(ids)]

print(res)

   user_id         event
3        2  registration
4        2      external
```

Answer (score 1):

you need,

```
 #find the user ids wchich has `external`
 user=df[df['event'].isin(['external'])]['user_id']
 #df, which has users
 df[df['user_id'].isin(user)]
```